# Is there a shorthand for guard return in swift?

Tags: swift, swift-guard

Is there is a way to have `guard` automatically return without needing to actually write it out every single time, e.g:

```
guard let url = self.webView.url else { return }
guard let componentDict = URLComponents(string: url.absoluteString)?.dict else { return }
guard let id = componentDict["v"] else { return }
guard let idUrl = URL(string: baseUrl + id) else { return }
```

In the case where I actually need to do something in addition to `return`, I would include the `else { return }` bit with my extra handling.

Its not a huge bother, but it would be a nice thing to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`guard` statement is typed with `else` must be, there is no shortcut for this but you can use `if..let` to avoid `else` statement.

Or combine this related variables statement with single `guard` statement

```
   guard let url = webView.url,
         let componentDict = URLComponents(string: url.absoluteString)?.dict,
         let id = componentDict["v"],
         let idUrl = URL(string: baseUrl + id)
         else { return }
```

Comment: Oh combining them is fantastic. Great compromise!

Answer (score 1):

You could write that code using `if let`:

```
if let url = self.webView.url,
   let componentDict = URLComponents(string: url.absoluteString)?.dict,
   let id = componentDict["v"],
   idUrl = URL(string: baseUrl + id) {
   // do something with idURL
} else {
    return // if needed
}
```

But in short, no, you can't shorten an individual `guard ... else { return }`.